# Return a range from a cell's address in an VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I have the following function to find a cell's range:

```
Function find_last_column()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Data_History")
    Set rng1 = ws.rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    find_last_column = rng1.Address
End Function
```

I'd like to use `rng1.Address` as a range in the following sub:

```
Sub Start_of_range()
    Dim starting_cell_string As Range
    starting_cell_string = find_last_column()
End Sub
```

I'd like to use `Offset` from `starting_cell_range' to then unload an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Set starting_cell_string = Range(find_last_column())
```

instead of `starting_cell_string = find_last_column()`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mashing up a string address and a range object.

```
Function find_last_column()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Data_History")
    Set rng1 = ws.rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    'might as well include the worksheet reference for added functionality (external:=true)
    find_last_column = rng1.Address(1, 1, xlA1, external:=true)
    set rng1 = nothing
    set ws = nothing
End Function

Sub Start_of_range()
    Dim starting_cell_string As STRING, starting_cell_range As RANGE
    starting_cell_string = find_last_column()
    set starting_cell_range = range(starting_cell_string)

    ' do stuff here

    set starting_cell_range = nothing
End Sub
```

I've change your var declaration for *starting_cell_string* in the `Start_of_range` sub to *String* which is what your function is returning. I've added a new *Range* object type variable (*starting_cell_range*) to `Set` to the cell(s) defined by the address string.

Comment: this is great!  Question for you: why set the variables to `nothing` at the end of the function?

Comment: @dwstein - Simply put, I do not trust VBA for object destruction. It takes very little to type and is a habit for me by now. see [When should an Excel VBA variable be killed or set to Nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing) for more detail.