# DAO Recordsets: Should I close and set to nothing if I am reusing the same name over and over?

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

Conceptually, which is better regarding memory leak and best practice:

```
Do
 set mTable = "something"
 'do a bunch of stuff
 mTable.Close
 Set mTable = nothing
Loop
```

Or:

```
Do
 set mTable = "something"
 'do a bunch of stuff
Loop
mTable.Close
Set mTable = nothing
```

Is one faster that the other?

Comment: The last is perfectly OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should an Excel VBA variable be killed or set to Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19038350/11683)

Comment: Thank you Gustav.

Comment: GSerg - thank you for the link. I read the thread and it is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the choice of my preference:

```
Do
     set mTable = "something"
     'do a bunch of stuff
     mTable.Close
Loop
Set mTable = nothing
```

`mTable.Close` commits the transaction, and you might run into troubles with too many nested transactions when running a large number of add or edit actions on the recordset (especially when working with attachments and multi-valued fields, which should be avoided if possible).

`Set mTable = Nothing` clears the reference to a closed recordset, and there's not really a reason to use this inside a loop, because you're reassigning something else to it after a couple of milliseconds.

It all depends on what you're doing exactly. As @Gustav stated, the last one is mostly fine. However, when editing and inserting, I prefer my option.

Comment: I will be editing the records in mTable so sounds like this may be the way to go. Thank you for the details. I'm self taught and have huge conceptual gaps and this helps me a lot.