# What happens to a modeless UserForm after the Sub terminates in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, model-view-controller, userform

What happens to a modeless Userform if I do this:

```
Sub testUIfrm()
Dim UIf As UIFrm

Set UIf = New UIFrm

With UIf
.Show
End With

End Sub
```

The sub runs until `End Sub` and will then terminate. The UserForm is still shown. But what happens with the `UIf` Object? According to my logic it should be terminated as soon as `End Sub` is hit. But the `UIf` is not terminated. (I have inserted a msgbox in the terminate event and this doesn't show.)

**So what is going on here when `End Sub` is executed?**

This thing seems very fishy to me..

Comment: `UIf` is set no `Nothing`. That [does not mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038890/11683) the object it used to store will be destroyed.

Comment: @GSerg and let me guess there is no way to prevent this?