# What do Set olMail = Nothing Set olApp = Nothing do in a VBA code to send emails via outlook from excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to edit an existing macro that sends out each row of a spreadsheet as an email. I want the macro to send out these emails in batches instead of all at once. 
I am using .`DeferredDeliveryTime` to do this.
The macro that I have has this at the end

```
Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
```

My question is if I remove this part will my deferred emails still be sent. I am afraid these lines will close outlook and the emails won't be sent.

Comment: My VBA code looks something like this - http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail4.htm

Comment: Those are [completely unnecessary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting to Nothing isn't necessary(in modern Excel versions 2010+). but there were issues with older versions of Excel (for which the workaround was to explicitly set).

It's just release an object and clear memory in VBA. For more information, you can refer the following link:

[When should an Excel VBA variable be killed or set to Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing/19038890)