# Why is the Immediate Window failing to display the values of my variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do something as simple as capturing the value of cells J1 and
I2 (name of column and row, respectively) from the following table, with J2 as a starting point.

[image: DataSource]

```
Sub FindTotal()

Dim strAddress As String
Dim rngValues As Range
Dim AssetNme As String, DateRng As String
Dim FrstValue As Integer

'Activate Sheet1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Request starting cell. Should be first cell of values in the matrix
strAddress = Application.InputBox("What is the first cell of values in the matrix?")
Set rngValues = Range(strAddress)
rngValues.Select

'Capture Asset and date
FrstValue = ActiveCell.Value
AssetNme = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
DateRng = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

End Sub
```

After I run the code, input J2 in the InputBox and press Enter, the assignments fail to show in the Immediate Window.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: ImmediateWindow]

Comment: You have to stop the code on `End Sub` to do this. When the code finishes, there is nothing there. Even better, use the line `Debug.Print FrstValue, AssetNme, DateRng` before `End Sub`.

Comment: All non-Static method-level (ie. Sub/Function) variables go out of scope as soon as your code ends, and get garbage-collected.

Comment: Here's more info about [debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should an Excel VBA variable be killed or set to Nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

This Visual studio bug is new for 2022 version. I tried Debug.Print(messagetoprint); then right click when stepping through it and opened the value in text Visualizer.  It shows the full value in there.