# How to get the return value from the stored procedure in VBA msgbox object

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @S int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_TestParams]
        @L1 = 2,
        @L2 = 2,
        @S = @S OUTPUT

SELECT  @S as N'@S'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Procedure executes the code `S = L1 + L2`.
Return code returns the value depending of the `S` value:
IF L1 is null or L2 is null SET ret_code = 0
ELSE IF S < 10 SET ret_code = 1
ELSE IF S >= 10 SET ret_code = 2

I'm using the following the VBA code to trigger the above procedure, asking for parameters `L1` and `L2` (in given question let's assume that both are equal 2) and want to display the both `@S` and `@return_value` in the msgbox, but I get an error that procedure or function has too many arguments.

```vb
Sub TriggerProcedure ()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MY_DATABASE;Uid=MY_LOGIN;Pwd=MY_PASSWORD;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    cn.Open
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SP_TestParams"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    
    Dim L1 As Integer, L2 As Integer, S As Integer, ret_code As Integer
    
    L1 = InputBox("Please enter parameter L1:")
    L2 = InputBox("Please enter parameter L2:")
    
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@L1", adInteger, adParamInput, , L1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@L2", adInteger, adParamInput, , L2)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@S", adInteger, adParamOutput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@return_value", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    
    cmd.Execute
    S = cmd.Parameters("@S").Value
    return_code = cmd.Parameters("@return_value").Value
    ret_code = cmd.Parameters("@return_value").Value
    
    MsgBox "Parametr S - sum" & L1 & " i " & L2 & " equal to" & S & vbNewLine & "Return code of the procedure is " & ret_code
    
    cn.Close
End Sub
```

The VBA code should display the results of the two queries (`S` & `return_code`).

Comment: "but receiving an error that procedure or function has too many arguments" - on which line does that show up?  You have not included L1 and L2 in your procedure declaration - that might be the problem.

Comment: Can you post the header for `[dbo].[SP_TestParams]` ?

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought the return value had to be the first parameter in ADODB.

Comment: **Side note:** you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I'm getting an error in line cmd.Execute.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the procedure there - we can't easily read it in a comment.

Comment: I'm not really a SQL server user, but don't you have a CREATE PROCEDURE script for `dbo.SP_TestParams` ?  That would be the most useful thing to show here...

Comment: Hmm... doesn't `cmd.Execute` return an `ADODB.RecordSet` object? Don't you need to consume the record set and close it before you can retrieve the output parameters? e.g.: [Retrieve values in SQL Server Stored Procedures with ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/retrieve-values-stored-procedure)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You do, but all that happens automatically at `.Execute` due to the [deterministic destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038890/11683) of the returned recordset right at that line. Besides, it would not cause a "wrong number of arguments" error.