VBA only hyperlinks indicated cells in one sheet but not the others
I have a VBA in which I'd like all cells, in all worksheets, that begin with HTTPS to be hyperlinked.
If I leave:
Set rng = ws.UsedRange - The code doesn't run and will not show errors.
If I define the Rng e.g. ("E1:E1000") it hyperlinks the cells but only for that worksheet not the rest. Also want to note that not all ranges I want hyperlinked are in column E
Sub HyperlinkHTTPSTextInAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim startString As String
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Define the range to search within the current worksheet
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange

        ' Loop through each cell in the defined range
        For Each cell In rng
            ' Check if the cell contains text and starts with "https"
            If VarType(cell.Value) = vbString And cell.Value Like "https*" Then
                ' Create a hyperlink for the text
                startString = cell.Value
                ' Remove existing hyperlink if present to avoid duplication
                If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then cell.Hyperlinks.Delete
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:=startString, TextToDisplay:=startString
            End If
        Next cell
    Next ws
End Sub


Looks fine to me - have you tried stepping through it?

Do you want to handle ThisWorkbook or ActiveWorkbook? ThisWorkbook is the workbook where the code is stored. If this is the workbook where your data is in, that's fine. ActiveWorkbook is the workbook that is currently displayed by Excel (has the focus). You usually use that if the code is in a different workbook (eg the Personal)

Not clear for me if you need to process **only column "E:E" of each sheet in workbook keeping the code, or something else...

@TimWilliams I have only changed Set rng = Range ("E1:E1000")  ... do I maybe have to define each worksheet so that it works in all the worksheets rather than just the one I am on?

That should be Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E1000"), right? But Set rng = ws.UsedRange should work.

@FunThomas ThisWorkbook is where the data is stored at as well. Should I try ActiveWorkbook?

Add Debug.Print ws.Name, rng.Address after the Set rng = ... line and check the output is what you expect.

@FunThomas It worked after the following changes:
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
and
Set rng = ws.UsedRange
Sorry for the formatting.

Thank you to everyone for the help, I appreciate it.

Sub HyperlinkHTTPSTextInAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim startString As String
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Define the range to search within the current worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Check if the worksheet is not empty
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            ' Loop through each cell in the defined range
            For Each cell In rng
                ' Check if the cell contains text and starts with "https"
                If VarType(cell.Value) = vbString And cell.Value Like "https*" Then
                    ' Create a hyperlink for the text
                    startString = cell.Value
                    ' Remove existing hyperlink if present to avoid duplication
                    If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then cell.Hyperlinks.Delete
                    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:=startString, TextToDisplay:=startString
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
        ' Clear the range object for the next iteration
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next ws
End Sub

Explanation: 
1- Error Handling: The On Error Resume Next statement before setting rng helps to skip over any potential errors when UsedRange is empty or invalid,  and On Error GoTo 0 turns off the error handling immediately after.
2- Range Check: Adding a check to ensure rng is not Nothing prevents processing empty worksheets.
3- Clear the Range Object: The Set rng = Nothing at the end of the loop ensures that the range is reset for each worksheet.

This doesn't address the problem of the OP. 1) + 2) UsedRange is never empty for a worksheet, so the error handling and the check if rng is Nothing is not needed. 3) Setting object variables to Nothing at the end of a routine doesn't do anything and is not needed either, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing
