Does SAP GUI scripting with python3 require you to release the connection or is it handled by the garbage collection?
This Post is mainly about scripting in Python but also VBA input is welcome
Both in the SAP script recording and in forum posts (e.g. by Stefan Schnell), the objects used for the connection are released again both in the event of a failed connection and before the end of the script (see python snippet):
def connect_and_release():
    
    try:
        [...]
        session = connection.Children(1)
        if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            connection = None  # "releasing"
            application = None  # "releasing"
            SapGuiAuto = None  # "releasing"
            return
        [...]

    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])

    finally:
        session = None  # "releasing"
        connection = None  # "releasing"
        application = None  # "releasing"
        SapGuiAuto = None  # "releasing"

I understand that if this function were integrated into a larger program, for example, and the objects were not released, the connection to the scripting would then exist permanently until the end of the program (visible, for example, in the rotating barber pole in SAP). My Questions are therefore:

if the script ends directly after the function, is the finally block necessary, or is the connection disconnected by the python garbage collection after the script ends anyway?
which of the listed objects actually have to be released so that, for example, SAP shows the scripting as no longer active. So if session is defined via connection, do I necessarily have to release both, or is it sufficient to release connection?
what are the implications towards excel VBA scripts? When using a private variable, do i neccessarily have to set to Nothing?

Please note that this is not about best practices but rather about understanding what happens under the hood.

You shouldn't mix different things into one question on SO, else it is hard or impossible to create one answer (that you can accept). For VBA: It is almost never necessary to set something to Nothing. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038350/when-should-an-excel-vba-variable-be-killed-or-set-to-nothing

@FunThomas That is why I wrote the disclaimer in bold on top that it is about python and VBA is only nice to have. But you are still propably right, maby I should edit the VBA part out?
